# Replacing a string's content with something from a list or dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the `string.replace()` with a list of specified things that I wish to find and replace:

```
string = 'Hello %*& World'
string.replace(['%','*','&'], ['pct','star','and'])
```

I'm sure a dictionary would make a lot more sense, but the example was just for you guys to try to understand what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `str.replace` multiple times...

```
string = 'Hello %*& World'
repl = ['%','*','&'], ['pct','star','and']
for a, b in zip(*repl):
    string = string.replace(a, b)
```

However, such a way of storing replacements doesn't look good. One possibility is to use a dictionary:

```
repl = {'*': 'star', '%': 'pct', '&': 'and'}
for a, b in repl.items():
    string = string.replace(a, b)
```

Also, if you know that the strings that are to be replaced are always just one character, `str.translate` can be more efficient. Use it like this:

```
repl = {'*': 'star', '%': 'pct', '&': 'and'}
repl = str.maketrans(repl)
string = string.translate(repl)
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, how is it supposed to work? You probably want to rename the files, but instead you just modify the string with file name and do nothing with it, so it's just lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary

```
>>> char_replace = {"%":"pct" , "*":"star" , "&":"and"}
>>> st = 'Hello %*& World'
>>> for i,j in char_replace.items():
...                st = st.replace(i,j)
...
>>> st
'Hello pctstarand World'
>>>
```

Just out of curiosity I tried to `time` all the ways to replace string characters discussed here. In case you were wondering which is better.

`1st way`

```
>>> setup= '''
... char_replace = {"%":"pct" , "*":"star" , "&":"and"}
... st = 'Hello %*& World'
... for i,j in char_replace.items():
...         st = st.replace(i,j)
... '''
>>> t = Timer(setup)
>>> t.timeit()
2.3223999026242836
>>>
```

`2nd way`

```
>>> setup1 = '''
... string = 'Hello %*& World'
... repl = ['%','*','&'], ['pct','star','and']
... for a, b in zip(*repl):
...     string = string.replace(a, b)
...
... '''
>>> t = Timer(setup1)
>>> t.timeit()
3.2493382405780267
```

`3rd way`

```
>>> setup2 = '''
... string = 'Hello %*& World'
... repl = {'*': 'star', '%': 'pct', '&': 'and'}
... repl = str.maketrans(repl)
... string = string.translate(repl)
...
... '''
>>> t = Timer(setup2)
>>> t.timeit()
3.3588874718125226
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have predetermined sets of what needs to be replaced and what needs to be the replacements, a nice way with a dictionary would be this:

```
string = 'Hello %*& World'
replacements = {}
replacements['%'] = 'pct'
replacements['*'] = 'star'
replacements['&'] = 'and'
for key in replacements:
    string = string.replace(key,replacements[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'Hello %*& World'
>>> translate_dict = {ord(key): value 
        for key, value in zip(['%','*','&'], ['pct','star','and'])}
>>> s.translate(translate_dict)
'Hello pctstarand World'
```

Comment: @JohnMachin, I should make a dict that I don't need and then have a function turn that into the dict I do need rather than just making the dict I do need?

Comment: Your starting point should be a legible dict `{'%': 'pct', etc}` instead of less legible and more mistake-prone parallel lists.

Comment: I used the same starting point as OP, which seems like it's probably the way to go.

Comment: The OP starting point was necessitated by his (attempted) use of str.replace. He also said "I'm sure a dictionary would make a lot more sense" etc. "probably the way to go"???